# Does FFMpeg random generate identical sequences of pseudo-random numbers for consecutive executions?

Tags: random, ffmpeg

For example if I execute command twice:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf geq=r='random(1)*255':g='random(1)*255':b='random(1)*255' -strict -2 output.mp4`

For the same source file, I have identical output files. Why? I want to get different output files.

Testing configuration:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.17-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 20160609
```

I suppose that's because randomizer start value is identical. Does ffmepg have function like srand?

More specifically I want to add random noise just like this: `noise=alls=20:allf=p+t+u`. But if I try do so I got the same noise for different executions on the same input file.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `all_seed` option:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "noise=alls=20:allf=p+t+u:all_seed=123457" random.mp4
```

Default value is `123457`. You will need to change that per execution. Perhaps with something like:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "noise=alls=20:allf=p+t+u:all_seed=$(tr -cd [:digit:] < /dev/urandom | head -c 9)" random.mp4
```

Verify with [hash demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hash):

```
ffmpeg -i random.mp4 -f hash -
[…]
SHA256=4e3c698661b0482684d2c38f7c075a4fd8bf46fadc665b4b0f53ff41e7d9266a
```

See [noise filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#noise).